Which is correct: "Mark it read" or "Mark it as read"?
It is common in modern life to update the status of something to one of several values. Marking an email "read" is just one example. An example from pre-digital times might be to mark a bill "paid."
I find that when I write a phrase like this, I experience a mental vibration between "Mark it paid" and "Mark it as paid."
I have the feeling that both are correct, but I wondered what others thought. Thank you in advance!

There's a distinction between stamping "PAID" on something and labeling it in some other way that allows the right people to know it has been paid. "Mark it 'paid'" probably means put "paid" on it, while "mark it paid" or "mark it as paid" doesn't necessarily.

You are right, I suspect, that << 'Mark it as read. >> and << Mark it 'read'. >> (the latter a factitive usage, and the quotes highlighting the label conferred) are the basic structures. However, along with more obvious quote structures such as << Say hello to him for me. >> the quotes are increasingly often dropped to give a pseudo-quote structure.

The word as is optional in mark it [as] paid, same as with many other verbs (label, stamp, designate,...), and there can be a slight nuance of difference as identified by @calvenable's answer. But it's mandatory with some verbs (treat it as X, identify it as X,...), and it's not idiomatic to include as with some verbs (call it X, find it X,...).

Although the other question is relevant to this one, this is hardly its duplicate. The focus of the other question is on the use of quotation marks or italics, while the focus of this one is on the role of as.

SO even has a button to mark all your notifications as read. So, perhaps as read is more natural. But does it have to do anything with past participles acting as adjectives/adverbs? If one was marking boxes with either a blue label or a red label, wouldn't they say, "Oh, those? I marked them all red"?

"Mark it as paid/read." is the more natural phrasing for an English speaker.
The phrase "Mark it 'paid'" sounds more like a literal instruction to e.g. stamp the word PAID on a physical invoice or letter, whereas to mark something as paid allows for a more general interpretation of the imperative, implying "mark this in any way that indicates it has been paid". The latter sounds more natural to a native speaker, though I can't pinpoint why.
Cambridge Dictionary lists the similar phrases "take something as read" and "marking someone down as something" which both include the 'as' rather than omitting it e.g. "I took it as read that this was the case." or "I had marked her down as this type of person."

Sometimes, the use of the word natural sounds quite odd to my ear.

In everyday usage similar phrases seem to be even more condensed, often simply phrased as "Mark(ed) as paid" or "Mark(ed) as read".
